# Disable generation of requests and routing specs? [RSPEC]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, generator

Whenever I generate a scaffold, Rspec generator always creates specs like the following:

```
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/controllers/stars_controller_spec.rb
  invoke      helper
  create      spec/routing/stars_routing_spec.rb
  invoke      rspec
  create        spec/requests/stars_spec.rb
```

How can I make sure that these are never generated? I tried setting configuration settings like this, but it didn't help:

```
  config.generators do |g|
   g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
   g.view_specs false
   g.integration_specs false
   g.helper_specs false
  end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
    :view_specs    => false,
    :request_specs => false,
    :routing_specs => false
end
```

ps - [see the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) for more info.

Comment: I couldn't find that :view_specs key documented anywhere at relishapp.com, but it worked for me, using rails 3.0.17 and rspec 2.6.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can you find these options?

Documentation can be out of date. However, the list of options can be found in [RSpec Rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) library.

- [Options for rspec-rails 5.1](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/5-1-maintenance/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb#L17-L21).
- [Latest options from main, but obviously, may be moved.](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb)

```rb
class_option :controller_specs, type: :boolean, default: false, desc: "Generate controller specs"
class_option :request_specs,    type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate request specs"
class_option :view_specs,       type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate view specs"
class_option :helper_specs,     type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate helper specs"
class_option :routing_specs,    type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate routing specs"
```